# How to put items next to each other using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Im not very much familiar with flex box but i assumed the following would give me the result i need,i need to give left side of the page to items(cards)but the way they position should be next together :

```
div class="flexContainer">

    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
    <mat-card  class="turbineIcons"></mat-card>
  </div>
```

here is my class for the main div:

```
  .flexContainer{
     width: 50%;
                }

  .turbineIcons{               
          background-color:white;
          margin: 1em;
          height: 20px;
          width: 20px;
      }
```

this shows all the items verticaly placed on the left side of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding to the css of you flex-container:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the flex properties.

Add this:

```
.flexContainer {
   display: flex;
   width: 50%;
 }
```

Comment: but now it takes up whole the width even thought i put 50%

Comment: Try `display: inline-flex`

Comment: Erica approach works,your also,who should i give the selected answer?